# jQuery each only affects last element

Tags: jquery, each

my each statement will only affect the last element. I'd like to guess it has something to do with my variable logic, but I don't see how that makes sense as I'm targeting inside that statement using $(this)

JS

```
$("form").each( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $submit = $this.find('.submit');
    $textarea = $this.find('textarea');

    $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $textarea.keyup(function(){

        var validated = true;

        var validated = ($textarea.val().length === 0) ? false : true;

        if(validated) {
            $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
    $textarea.trigger('keyup');
});
```

Basic HTML:

```
<form>
    <textarea rows="13"></textarea>
    <button class="btn submit">Chercher</button>
</form>
<form>
    <textarea rows="13"></textarea>
    <button class="btn submit">Chercher</button>
</form>
```

Comment: works fine for me.. checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NG4MP/ also. `var validated=true` is redundant

Comment: I'd suggest using a class for your textarea. Makes the whole code simpler. Oh, and prefixing JS variables with a `$` is rather unusual..

Comment: @lethal-guitar: The `$` prefix for variables holding jQuery objects is quite common.

Comment: @lethal-guitar Actually very common, lets you know the variable is a jQuery wrapped object, not just some integer / string etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm, didn't know that.. Interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're not declaring those variables, so they're not local to the function, only a *single* variable is used and is overwritten by each call to the iterator function (and if you haven't declared them anywhere, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)). Add `var` in front of your variables to make them specific to each call to the iterator function, e.g.:

```
$("form").each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $submit = $this.find('.submit');
    var $textarea = $this.find('textarea');
    // ...
```

Comment: I've had that bad practice for quite a while, heh :P

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'form textarea', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.submit').prop('disabled', $this.val().length === 0)
});
$('form textarea').trigger('keyup')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7C9J/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Script**

```
var $this, $submit, $textarea, validated;
$("form").each( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $submit = $this.find('.submit');
    $textarea = $this.find('textarea');

    $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $textarea.keyup(function(event){

        validated = ($(this).val().length === 0) ? false : true;

        if(validated) {
            $(this).next().removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
    $textarea.trigger('keyup');
});
```

**Demo JS** http://jsfiddle.net/dhfBE/

Comment: works just as TJ Crowder's solution, I didn't know you could define multiple variables at once

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible without any assignments and without an explicit `each`.

Try :

```
$("form textarea").on('keyup', function() {
    $(this.form).find('.submit').attr("disabled", this.value.length === 0);
}).trigger('keyup');
```